# Problem from Williams' Probability with Martingales

Tags: probability

> Let $G$ be the free  group with two generators $a$ and $b$. Start at time $0$ with  the unit element $1$, the empty word. At each second, multiply the current word by one of the four elements $a$, $b$,  $a^{-1}$,  $b^{-1}$, choosing each with probability $\frac{1}{4} $ (independently of previous choices). Prove that the probability that reduced word $1$ ever occurs is $\frac{1}{3}$.

I have a solution using generating functions but I found $\frac{1}{4}$. Thanks in advance for any hint or solution.

My solution :
denote by $A_{n} :word \ 1 \ occurs \ at \ time \ n$  then it's clear that $ P(A_{2n+1})=0$ furthermore : $ A_{2n}$ is  true iff  the word at time $2n$ is of type $ xx^{-1}$ where $x$ is a word of length $n$ , hence : $P(A_{2n})= \frac{1}{4^{n}}$

Now let : $ T_{i}$ the time  at which we hit the $1$ $i$ times

for i=2  :  we have $P(T_{2} =2n+1) =0 $ we notice also that once we hit $1$ the process is memoryless in other words :

$$P(T_{2} =2n)= \sum_{k=1}^{k=n-1} P(T_{2}=2n|T_{1}=2k)P(T_{1}=2k)
              =\sum_{k=1}^{k=n-1} P(T_{1}=2n-2k)P(T_{1}=2k)$$
let's forget about the initial condition ie ,we set : $P(T_{1}=0)=0$ since $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are even we set : $ T_{1}=2t_{1} ,T_{2}=2t_{2} $

We have :
 $$ P(t_{2}=n) =\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}P(t_{1}=n-k)P(t_{1}=k) $$

For $0\leq x <1 $ denote by: $$ G_{i}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(t_{i}=n)x^{n} $$

by the last equality  we have : $$ G_{2}(x)= G_{1}(x)^{2}$$ and  in the same manner that : $$  G_{i}(x)=G_{1}(x)^{i}$$

We have also : $$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} G_{i}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(t_{i}=n)x^{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{2n})x^{n} $$

What is left now is trivial computations  we find that our desired probability $$ G_{1}(1)= \frac{1}{4} $$

Comment: What's the full book title please?

Comment: Probability with martingales by David Williams

Comment: The problem is your calculation of $P(A_{2n})$. It is not true that the probability of getting $x x^{-1}$ is $1/4^n$; it depends on the length of the reduced word $x^\prime$ for $x$. For instance, if $x=1$ there are lots of ways to fill in the remaining $n$ slots to arrive at $x^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho$ be the probability of ever getting an empty word, starting with a word of length 1. Then by first step analysis, $\rho={1\over 4}+{3\over 4}\rho^2$ and solving  gives $\rho=1/3.$